# Allow users with a gold specialist badge in a tag to manually sort answers

Tags: feature-request, badges, answers, sorting

We sometimes have the problem where a [wrong answer can float to the top of a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14514/more-downvote-power-to-op).

If we allow users who have earned a gold specialist badge to manually sort answers to a question, they could move the erroneous answer down to allow the correct answer to float to the top.

The users would only be able to sort the answers in a question tagged with the tag they have the badge in.

Comment: Not too popular of an idea...

Comment: -1 for excessive complexity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually gold badge users are recognised and respected by users familiar with their badge - if they downvote an answer and explain their reasoning in a comment, that comment is likely to be treated seriously, often provoking more downvotes.

In other words, I don't think any more powers are required.

Comment: *"Usually gold badge users are recognised and respected"* -- maybe I have an inferiority complex, but I don't feel this happening that much.

Comment: @mmyers: I'm pretty sure he means the people who have earned a gold **tag** badge.

Comment: I do have a gold tag badge.

Comment: I know.  And I respect you for it.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Or, more elaborate: No!

Okay, a little more: No! That's totally contrary to the whole idea of the SO family.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to say no, because the system works pretty well as is.  The only questions that I think get out of hand are the super long wiki type questions with 13 pages of answers/suggestions/opinions.

Answer (score 0):

I have a better idea: if you find a question with a high-ranked but wrong answer, post it here and we'll sputter on about how it's such a travesty and the voters are on crack and SO is irreparably broken... and then go down-vote it en-masse, leaving nothing but a smoking pile of broken dreams and kicked puppies.

...or point out why it's actually **not** such a bad answer after all, and how you're an idiot for failing to understand it's **brilliance.** And then go down-vote *everything you've ever posted, ever.*

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that someone who earns a gold tag badge is going to be the properly qualified individual to make that type of decision. It is entirely possible just to earn a gold badge for a tag through sheer attrition and volume and not because you are ever actually correct.

Comment: Possibly, but unlikely to have happened much yet. Over time it'll happen more and more, however. One of the implicit points of my answer (which maybe I should have made explicit) is that by relying on the normal system, the rest of the community has its attention drawn to the concerns of the gold badge holder, but can make up their own minds about the validity of those concerns.