# Helping users accept answers

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers, accepted-answer

I find a lot of the time users who don't accept answers are usually new(er) users. They don't know  that the accept option is there or they just don't know how to do it. I know this because a lot of the time I'll add a comment as such:

> Glad to help! If this answer helped you out you should [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it!

And they're comment back telling me they didn't know about it.

A lot of the time I notice they will add comments like:

- *"Thanks, this helped"*
- *"It's working now, thanks!"*
- *"Just what I was looking for! Thanks!"*
- [*"Thanks Pieter B! That did just what I was looking for :)"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052126/incrementing-in-a-select-statement/19053872#19053872)

If key words such as those are detected, there should be a small one liner telling them they should consider accepting the answer or maybe even go so far as to add a checkbox or button next to the comment to allow them to accept an answer. Maybe an illustrated example will help:

[image]

Or:

[image]

I know it seems like a small change but I think it'll help newer users learn about accepting answers.

Also, the *accepting* link points to [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that having an accepted answer is important.  It is not.  Having no answer accepted doesn't cause any real significant problems.  There are so many more important things for new users to learn

Comment: I disagree. It is important. It gives you rep, shows what really helped the poster, it allowed users on SO who want to answer questions avoid questions that have already been answered, etc. Just read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163740/actually-how-important-is-accepting-an-answer-to-the-stack-exchange-model)

Comment: Up-votes show future readers what *many* users found helpful or useful, which is often more uvaluable than whether or not it helped the *one* OP. And in many cases the answer the OP accepted is simply the first answer, not necessarily the best answer; and [in some cases the accepted answer is not even right](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49619/wrong-last-modified-date-of-ndf-file-on-sql-server/).

Comment: I always very annoyed with people asking exactly that. Already less than 5 minutes after they put it. I wish there wasn't such a thing like accepted answers, just voting based whether it's a good answer or not, that's it.

Comment: In addition to Aaron's point, most people helped by SO questions get there from google, and from google there's no indication as to whether there's an accepted answer.  As for the rep, rep itself isn't particularly important, so that you're getting it isn't a major issue.

Comment: Yep, I agree. But there's more benefits to accepting answers than just noting that it was helpful to the OP. Check the link I provided above. I'm not saying that it's absolutely critical to get it done, but it's important and it plays a role on SO and other stack exchange sites.

Comment: @Michael Or if it just didn't give rep; if the checkmark in the UI was the end of it that'd be fine.

Comment: While I've been skeptical of earlier suggestions along those lines, I think a line saying something like "If this answer solved your problem, consider accepting it" would be a good solution. It's similar to the [suggestion to explain downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes), which itself tries to make an annoying comment ("@downvoter please explain") unnecessary

Comment: @SeanWM No, it's not particularly important.  It does serve a purpose, but it's a tangential one that's quite a bit less important than many other tools on the site.  Just because it can be helpful doesn't mean it's *important* or that there's a need to go out of our way to push users into accepted answers.  If they want to use it, the feature is there, if they don't, that *fine*.  I did look at the link, I don't find it's arguments, nor yours, compelling.

Comment: @Servy I think accepting answers _is_ important, solely for the reason that it's the only way for future visitors to know whether the original author's question has been solved. The rep points is inconsequential, and I wish people wouldn't dwell on that. It's a basic workflow question.

Comment: @Servy true indeed. It would at least stop this never ending annoying begging. "Could you please accept my answer?". I so hate that.

Comment: @RobertRyan If the answers *didn't* answer the OP's question they should be commenting on the answers to indicate that they didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Servy I'm against nagging users to accept, but if they go and say answer works on their own will, why not to remind them automatically about "accepted" mark? Not forcing. Nothing obtrusive. Just like the message about comments when you downvote. And only to those who appear to say they accept in their comments. What's wrong with that? And with it implemented, comments like "please accept" could be forbidden.

Comment: @Mołot That's nagging users to accept an answer, which you say you're against.

Comment: @Servy Lol. No, just because an answer didn't solve the original question, doesn't make it a comment. There are plenty of questions out there with great answers that, ultimately, didn't resolve the issue. I agree that I don't like people nagging with "please accept", but I also think that SeanWM's suggestion is a great one.

Comment: @RobertRyan there could be a 100 reasons why he accepted that one. Maybe it was the first and he couldn't be bothered changing it, maybe he was looking for simple hack rather than a solution, maybe he was a beginner and just choose for one that looked the easiest, maybe a better answer came one year later, maybe he was even drunk. I never think I should take that answer because the answerer said it worked. I always read the answers and take the votes into account and then make my decission.

Comment: @Servy nope, it does not appear in comment list, does not appear in inbox, is visible only for few seconds and only if triggered by user's own action - way more delicate than what's happening now pretty often.  When you downvote, do you feel someone is forcing you to comment? I'm talking about similar mechanism

Comment: @RobertRyan If the answers are great then honestly, the site is working fine.  Remember, the goal of the site is to create a repository of knowledge that can benefit the internet as a whole, not to just help the one person asking a question.  Helping that person is a secondary goal.  If great answers are being created, then we're good.  If the OP feels that the great answer doesn't help them, they can (and usually do) comment indicating what their remaining problems are, in the event the answer needs to be improved.

Comment: @David but it doesn't. I see "down-voter please explain" all the time (and I've been guilty of it too, though more recently I've been flagging it as not constructive nonsense).

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I said it "tries to make it" unnecessary, not that it can eliminate it completely. In any case, I don't see how an automated suggestion for accepting is against the site's philosophy if an automated suggestion for commenting after downvoting isn't. It's true that accepting is entirely up to the OP, but it's equally true that commenting is entirely up to the downvoter.

Comment: New users are usually a little uncoordinated. Eventually they will accept an answer, all it requires is a little patience. In the mean time, if the answer was valid then the community will support it.

Comment: @David they're different. Down-voting is a boolean. Trying to parse an OP's comment ("this worked" vs. "I up-voted the other answer because it worked better") is a little more complex.

Comment: Appears to be new request, voting to reopen.

Answer (score 10):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Wording

   If this suggestion is pursued, I'd suggest some wording changes. Specifically, this seems to conflate the distinction between an up-vote (i.e. this was helpful, an option only available when you have sufficient reputation) and accepting an answer (i.e. this answered my question and it's the best solution I received). Simply being helpful doesn't make it a candidate for accepting.

   So, instead of "Did this answer help you?", perhaps "Did this answer your question?"
2. User interface

   Instead of a separate message, maybe just clarify/supplement the text that appears in the existing comment box:

   [image]

My reservation on the suggested feature request is that I would like to see noobs wait a bit before accepting the first answer that popped in. Often, the first answer is not the best one, so I'm not sure we'd want to have a UI that led people to accept the first answer that came in.

Personally, rather than a one-liner that presumes to tell the author of the question what to do, I might simply suggest showing a link to [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Good idea to link to the Help center rather than any other possible text.

Answer (score 2):

Oddly I was pondering this today.  My thoughts are that if the user is fairly new, has several questions which have good answers (and the typical "this works!1!! thx!!1!!" comment) they may not fully understand the mechanics of SO.  Here is a [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14999/228270) for high-rep cred ;)

Anyway, here is my proposed comment in these situations:

> I've noticed that you've asked several questions that have received successful, helpful answers but you haven't accepted any of them. Here are a couple useful links that describe the typical StackOverflow QA etiquette: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)